# UWP intercept window.print()

Tags: uwp

In my UWP App i try to intercept window.print() so that when a user press the button in a page that my C# code takes over todo the printing.

I tried different methods but my ScriptNotify event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have include the page's **Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)** in the `ApplicationContentUriRules` section of the app manifest when you want to enable an external web page to fire the `ScriptNotify event` when calling window.external.notify

Please check this document- [Interacting with WebView content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview?view=winrt-19041#interacting-with-webview-content) for more information.